# Where to instantiate context.xml in Test Environment

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testing

We are using Spring Framework (XML Version) 4.0.5.RELAESE in our Java project.
In our application the context.xml is instantiated at the begin of the application start, and provides every properties via dependecy injection.

Now I am wondering what is the best (and commonly used) strategy on where to instantiate it in the test environment. (We have some Unit, Integration and System tests who at least need the databaseBaseConnector bean provided in the context.xml,)

I thought about making an abstract class which every test extends from, but in this case it would be newly instantiated before every test. I would like to a have a solution similiar to the main application, where the context is only instantiated one time, and everything else needed is set via dependency injection.

Researching this topic didn`t help much yet, so I decided to ask the question.

Comment: spring provides the SpringJUnit4ClassRunner framework for junit built in. you would just have to configure the application context in the junit itself directly. you can have a look into it for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring comes with an `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` and a `@ContextConfiguration` -annotation. If you use them, then spring will reuse the same Spring Context in different tests.

So a Spring test class can look like this:

```
package com.queomedia;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
//@Transactional
@ContextConfiguration(SpringTestContext.APPLICATION)
public class SpringContextTest {

    @Autowire
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    //Test that the spring context can been loaded
    @Test
    public void testSpringContextLoad() {
        Assert.assertNotNull("application context expected", this.applicationContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably meant '@Autowired', also do you have an idea why I can`t resolve SpringTestContext?